# Browser not saving field values i.e address in browser autofill settings (chrome) on submission of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, autofill

I Have created one registration form with below code in react.js , which is properly working fine but i want to make change in form submittion like rather than writing event on anchor tag for saving form
Can we use React-Form for form submission ? or else how to use React form to save fields.

Below is my code snippet -

```
<form className="clearfix" name = "signup" id = "signup" method = "post" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit = {this.signupUser} autoComplete = "on">
    <input autocomplete="given-name" name="firstName" type="text"  placeholder="Enter First Name" class="form-control" value="">
    <input autocomplete="family-name" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" class="form-control" value="">
    <input autocomplete="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" value=""> 
    <input autocomplete="tel" name="phoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" class="form-control contactMask" value="">
    <input autocomplete="address-line1" name="addressLine1" type="text" placeholder="Street 1" class="form-control">
    <input autocomplete="address-line2" name="addressLine2" type="text" placeholder="Street 2" class="form-control" value="">
    <button className="btn baseBtn primeBtn" value = "Post" type = "submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Below is react onSubmit function : -

```
   signupUser: function() {
    this.setState({
        signUpError: ''
    });
    if (!this.validateAll() || this.isApiInProgress) {
        return;
    }
    this.isApiInProgress = true;
    UserStore.userSignup(this.params).then(function() {
      this.transitionTo('signupSuccess');
    }.bind(this), function(errorMessage) {
        this.isApiInProgress = false;
        this.setState({
            signUpError: errorMessage
        });
    }.bind(this));
},
```

On click of signUp, Browser shoud save the form **and should also save the the values in browser autofill.** currently it is not saving field values in browser autofill.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://prometheusresearch.github.io/react-forms/examples/basic.html) it is possible and works together with an `onSubmit` function that you need to implement in your React class.

To save your field contents, you can add them to the component state, e.g. `onBlur`. The `handleBlur` function would call `this.setState` to add the information to the component state, and via `this.state` you can pull it out and insert it into the field in your render method.

Comment: Will it autofill field values in browser on submit ?

Comment: Sorry, I answered your question "Can I use <button type="submit"> ?" I don't know whether it will work with the browser auto-fill.